# Why does TS infer the type of an inline function but not that of an external function?

Tags: typescript

```
function hof(cb: (a: string) => string): void {}

// @ts-expect-error
function someFunc(a) {
  return a.toUpperCase();
}

// Here TS has inferred that the inline function is of type 
// (a: string) => string
hof((a) => a.toUpperCase());

// But here it doesn't
hof(someFunc);
```

In the above snippet TS can infer the type of the inline function `(a) => a.toUpperCase()` but it cannot infer the type of `someFunc`, why?

Answer (score 2):

The inline function definition benefits from [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing); the context in which the function is defined gives the compiler a hint that it should be of type `(a: string) => string`, and thus that the function's first parameter will be of type `string`.

On the other hand, your `someFunc` definition has no such associated context.  It is a standalone function statement whose type needs to be determined by the compiler completely independently of whether or not you ever pass it to `hof()`.  You *could* argue that the mere existence of `hof(someFunc)` somewhere in your program could be used as context for the definition of `someFunc`, but such analysis would be incredibly costly as well as surprising, since it would be highly nonlocal.  Thus the `someFunc` definition has no context for the `a` parameter, and it is implicitly given the `any` type (which is an error with [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) from the [`--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)).

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript knows that the argument `hof` tags is `(value: string) => string`, so when you have an inline function it can infer the argument from the context.

When you separate the function and store it in a variable, it is no longer associated with `hof`, so it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The inline function is meant to be used *only* by `hof`, so TS can infer it's type safely.

But when the function is defined elsewhere and it's reference is passed to `hof`, TS *cannot* assume that the function is *only* meant to be used by `hof` because it can be used in other places as well. The only thing TS wants *now* is that the function that is being passed to `hof` is type compatible with what `hof` expects, in other words the type of the function being passed should be compatible with type: `(a: string) => string`.

And this becomes more clear when you observe the complaint by TS, the complaint is *not* at all related to `hof`, even if you remove all the other code and just have the `someFunc` function definition, TS would still be complaining, so there's *no* association between `someFunc` and `hof` and TS is simply complaining because of the implicit `any` type that the parameter `a` gets (refer to the [`--noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) compiler option).

If you explicitly state that argument `a` could be of type `any`, then there would be *no* complaints because `(a: any) ⇒ string` is compatible with `(a: string) => string`.

Finally, let's consider the following example:

```
function hof1(cb: (a: string) => string): void {}
function hof2(cb: (a: number) => string): void {}

function someFunc(a: string | number): string {
  return `${a}`;
}

hof1((a) => a.toUpperCase());
hof2((a) => a.toFixed(2));

hof1(someFunc);
hof2(someFunc);
```

In the example `someFunc` is being used for both `hof1` and `hof2`, so it makes it more clear why TS wasn't able to make any assumption, because `someFunc` is more generic as compared to what either `hof1` or `hof2` accepts. But with that inline function TS knew that it's exactly what `hof` accepts because that's the only place it can be used.